# How to restart the timer in JFrame Java?

Tags: java, swing, timer, jframe

How can I restart the timer? I tried adding the  variable of int `i` inside the reset button. How can I solve this problem?

Below are the codes of the `Timer` that I have created.

```
import javax.swing.Timer;
import java.awt.event.*;
/**
 *
 */
public class JFrame2 extends javax.swing.JFrame {
int score1=0;
int score2=0;
int i = 25;

    /**
     * Creates new form JFrame2
     */
    public JFrame2() {
        initComponents();
    }
Timer T = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener()
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    i--;
    if(i>=0){
        shotclock.setText(""+i);
    }
}

});

  private void jButton5ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        T.start();
    }                                        

    private void jButton6ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
       T.stop();
    }                                        

    private void jButton7ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
int i = 25;                                         
        T.start();
    }
```

Comment: There is a `restart()` function in `Timer` class. Does it not do what you want?

Comment: I used the function as well but it didn't restart the timer back from the original starting time.

Comment: Is it possible to share your whole code? I need to reproduce it on my end. Also, `restart()` only *restarts* the timer, it *will **not*** re-initialize any variables.

Comment: *it didn't restart the timer back from the original starting time.* -  The purpose of a Tmier is to generate an event at the specified time interval.  If you want to reset the "I" variable to 25, then your code seems reasonable. When the Timer restarts is should start counting down from 25 again. If this is not happening then post a proper [mre] demonstrating the problem. Use meaningful variable names. What is "i" supposed to represent? And what is "T". Variable names should NOT start with an upper case character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it didn't restart the timer back from the original starting time

```
int i = 25;
```

That is because you created a new local variable.

You need to reset your original instance variable:

```
//int i = 25;     
i = 25;
```